# How can I retrieve my created collection?

Tags: google-chrome, postman, postman-native-app

Created **a collection** and a bunch of requests in the postman app. After turnoff from the chrome with clean data lost my  Postman all collection information. I Checked windows 10 following location to get IndexedDB but the location is empty. What to do? How can to retrieve my created collection?

```
C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming\Postman\IndexedDB\
```

Comment: did you tried login to postman web api]

Comment: @not yet, Just turnoff from chrome and checked clear data and my postman become blank.

Comment: postman is a cloud based solution login to postman web app and it might be available in that or in web app trash. (If it was synced correctly )

Comment: why IndexedDB is missing? what happened, is it store in another location?

Answer (score 0):

postman is cloud-based so it would available in web app :

https://app.getpostman.com/

it seems like your postman is corrupted

you should reinstall postman

Can you try deleting the “Postman” folder or renaming it to “Postman.old” from below two locations and then reinstall the latest version from here 5 and see if that helps?

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming
```

Stop all running instance of postman by going to task manager